# How should I connect to a VPN Tunnel from Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vpn, openvpn

I just built an Ubuntu server and I need to connect to a secure tunnel from my client. On our windows servers (to this client) we use TheGreenBow VPN Client. And that works fine.

I bought a License for the LINUX VPN Client from TheGreenBow but it is not supported nor do I think will it work on Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS.

It was for an older version.

I did successfully install it (took many tries) but the web-based UI to configure the tunnel on http://localhost:3000 (per the installation instructions) it never comes up. Chrome just sits there. And yes the vpn service is enabled.

So I am looking for advice on which VPN Client you think I should use?

This is the tunnel protocol my client uses.

```
Phase 1 Proposal: 
----------------------
IKE Version: IKEv2 
DH Group: Group ** 
Encryption Algorithm: AES-256 
Hash Algorithm: SHA-2 (256 Bits) 
Lifetime: 28,800 seconds 
PSK: ***************
```

And they do not want to use PPTP, not for our production machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell which Diffie Hellman Group it is proposing as it seems to be a 2 character wildcard. See here if StrongSwan IKEv2 supports the DH Group :

- https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IKEv2CipherSuites

Try network-manager-strongswan if you want a GUI IPsec IKEv2 client.